# How does garbage collection work in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, garbage-collection

I understand that Objects not referenced by anything are garbage collected, and have been making sure to null out referenced to objects when I'm done with them. What I want to know are a few things:

1. Do only Objects need to be null-referenced? Number, int, String, etc
   are okay to leave, right? Is there a best practice for this?
2. How often does garbage collection usually run? Does it tend to run
   when processor demand is low?
3. Is there a way I can tell garbage collection to run manually, such
   as when I'm done with a playing field full of sprites? This is not
   really needed if garbage collection tends to run when processor use
   is low, since it will run anyway at the times I'd like it to.
4. Objects created just for the scope of an if or for statement etc, unless they are 
   assigned a reference elseware, are eligible for garbage collection, right?

Comment: Just an FYI on number 4: there is no block scope in actionscript. Only `local` and `global`. Any variable defined in a `for` or `if` usually belongs to its function, and won't fall out of scope until its function is done. Also closures keep scopes alive longer than you might think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gskinner has a good [article](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html) about GC in flash player

1. Only objects created by the new operator should be null-referenced, the curly brace operator ({x:5, y:5}) and the square bracket operator ([1,2,3]) should be null-referenced.
2. The garbage collector uses a set of heuristics that look at the RAM
   allocation and the size of the memory stack, among other things, to
   determine when to run.
3. You can use System.gc() to run it manualy in FP10, but it works only
   in debug player.
4. Yes, that's right

Comment: 1. This makes it very clear for me - anything I use "new" on, I need to set to null later. Awesome! 
2. Does this mean it usually runs only when memory starts to get full, or also when processor demand is low? I think I'm mainly concerned about the mark sweep part of garbage collection.

Comment: GC is triggered when your application fills the allocated memory of your app instance. It doesn't depend on processor demand.

Comment: That's a shame. I would love to be able to trigger (or even request) garbage collection at times when I know the program won't be doing much. I guess it's just up to me to make sure unused items are disconnected or recycled. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In Flash 11, you can give the system a hint that now is a good time to do garbage collection: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent%28%29

Comment: Fix your answer : 1. Only objects created by the new operator, the curly brace operator (`{x:5, y:5}`) and the square bracket operator (`[1,2,3]`) should be null-referenced.